# What taxes do I pay working remotely for a UK based company while living in the US?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, united-kingdom, working-at-home

I am UK citizen and will be moving to the US in January next year to marry my fiancé, but I'm going to continue working for my UK based company remotely from the States. Will I need to pay income tax both in the UK and the US?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you a permanent employee or a contractor ?

Comment: A long answer would be quite long, and would involve a discussion of what country you are really a 'resident' of [it is not always clear that you change residency on the day you move to a new country]. The short answer is that you probably will file tax returns in both countries, should likely expect to pay total taxes equal to the higher amount owed either to the US or the UK, due to the tax treaties between these countries. How you calculate this is quite in-depth; I recommend you look into hiring professional tax help with knowledge of foreign taxes.

Comment: @DumbCoder - I'm a permanent employee and have been for 10 years

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - I thought it might be a complicated answer. Thanks for you reply :) I figured I may need to hire a tax advisor.

Comment: @SCassidy If you have already broached the move to your employer, I highly recommend you seek help through your company. It is very common for companies who hire expats to either arrange for professional tax help in the new country, or potentially subsidize professional help that you need to hire. This would typically only apply if your company is big enough that they do this with some regularity.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: You should combine both your comments as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Grade'Eh'Bacon - I did try to combine both comments into one answer but it wouldn't let me include two name tags.
My company isn't big enough to arrange professional tax help for me, so I'll have to look into that myself. Thanks for the advice.